# Should I do anything about log entries like "redefining \cdots on input line 2739"?

Tags: logging

I know that many things in a LaTeX log file are not serious problems.  Some used to be more serious when computers had less resources, for example.  And this kind of report has not caused me any problems that know of.

But I wondered if it would be a better practice for me to try to avoid them.  If it would, then how should I try to do that?

Comment: It's not an error: it's an informational message. Here, the point is to tell you that `\cdot` has an altered indention.

Comment: @JosephWright  Right.  And what is the point of telling me \cdot did that?  Can I use that information in some way?

Comment: The `.log` in LaTeX is largely for debugging. Broadly, the idea is that anything which _might_ alter how a document looks gets logged. So changing the definition of any document command is recorded so _if_ you have an issue you can spot it. Not everyone thinks of the log quite like this, of course ...

Comment: @JosephWright I like to close questions.  If you post that as an answer i will accept it.  If you prefer not to then I will put that info into an answer.

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry, i did not mean "close" in the Stack Exhange sense.  I meant I like to get questions finished with accepted answers.